# Error installing RMySQL (MySQL 5.5.37 in Ubuntu 14.04 )

Tags: r, ubuntu, rmysql

Every time I try installing RMySQL I get the following error:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/ehsan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘RMySQL’ ...
** package ‘RMySQL’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for compress in -lz... yes
checking for getopt_long in -lc... yes
checking for mysql_init in -lmysqlclient... yes
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking mysql.h usability... no
checking mysql.h presence... no
checking for mysql.h... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h     -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c RS-DBI.c -o RS-DBI.o
cc1: warning: /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h: not a directory [enabled by default]
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h     -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c RS-MySQL.c -o RS-MySQL.o
cc1: warning: /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h: not a directory [enabled by default]
In file included from RS-MySQL.c:22:0:
RS-MySQL.h:32:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
 #include <mysql.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [RS-MySQL.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RMySQL’
* removing ‘/home/ehsan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RMySQL’
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpTRRPqg/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("RMySQL") :
  installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status**
```

Seemingly, it cannot find mysql.h and I searched and changed the path to

> export PKG_CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/R/include/mysql/mysql.h"

but it was not successful. There're many people who have had the same issue but non of their solutions (if existed) worked for me. I'd appreciate any comment or help.

<s>#Update: Issue Resolved#</s>

The following command seemed to solve the issue:

> sudo apt-get install r-cran-rmysql

Comment: You could write your own answer instead of editing an "issue resolved"

Comment: @RichardScriven, I prefer the more compact one!

Comment: Okay.  But I'm just saying that people sometimes will upvote your answer even if you answer your own question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As said, the following command worked for me:

> sudo apt-get install r-cran-rmysql

Comment: after installing install in R studio  then it works

Answer (score 6):

My this issue was resolved by executing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql++-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

since @ehsanmo hasn't posted his answer as an answer, then I will, and confirm that his solution works for me too:

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rmysql
```

(I'm on mint 12)

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two types of install/make problems. Missing .h files and/or missing .so/.a libs. As you can see from your log, you have a missing .h

The reason for these are multiple:
1.- the package that delivers these is not installed. This means that those files cannot be found anywhere in the /usr tree. **The solution is to install right package, make sure the files are there**

2.- **The includes are not found by the install configurator.** This means some environment variable or install option is not properly set. Which variable to set is usually specified in the documentation; in some cases you need to install something outside of R and again, that's usually specified in the documentation.

3.- the libs are not in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and hopefully the solution to that is self-explanatory.

4.- There is a deeper compile/link error, meaning the package is not compatible with the rest of the sw, or has not been properly ported.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies a lot.

Comment: Sure, no problem. This solution was actually based on an email my VP of IT sent me regarding package installation problems I was having with R on a Solaris HPC cluster. I made an Evernote from his email and I'm glad it came in handy here.

Answer (score 0):

**Setp :1**

```
find / -name mysql.h
```

If not found headers file is missing

**Setp :1**
Then  install or reinstall mysql-devel or mysql-client

```
sudo yum (re)install mysql-devel
sudo yum (re)install mysql-client

sudo yum (re)install mysql-community-devel
sudo yum (re)install mysql-community-client
```